# Program comes to a halt after executing second for loop in the sieve function

Tags: c++

Following is a c++ function which aims at applying sieve of eratosthenes. It has two for loops. First for the purpose of initialization and second for the application of sieve. This function when called from the main halts execution after second loop finishes iteration. Any suggestions what might be causing this sort of unfamiliar behaviour. I can't find any infinite loop running.

My code is available at this link -
 http://ideone.com/XArvT9

```
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if(b[i]==true)
    {
        k=2*i+3;
        primes.insert(k);
        fac[k]=1;
        for(j=2*i*i+6*i+3;j<n;j+=k)
        {
            b[j]=false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: @NathanOliver: nice boilerplate comment and link - I think I may have to steal this for future use.

Comment: why are you sieving WHILE you're initializing? your loops are nested, so your inner loop is going to be executed `n` times...

Comment: Why is prime number 2 not inserted into `primes`?

Comment: As my compiler would say: `fac[k] is set but not used`.

Comment: @Marc loops are nested as outer loop iterates through all the elements and searches for any prime number. Whereas the inner loop sets all the numbers that are divisible by some prime number to non-prime list.

Comment: @Thomas  Matthews 2 has already been inserted in the complete code as can be found on the ideone link. This programs aims at finding the total number of factors in prime-factorization of all numbers from 1 to 5Meg.

Comment: moreover this program executes well, it halts execution as soon as it finishes executing the for loops in sieve function